# Animation won't start if state changed (short snack for demonstration)

Tags: react-native, animation, react-navigation, listener, react-animated

**[Snack is here](https://snack.expo.io/4sln1SIMO)**

Hello, I'm hard stuck on a silly problem and I'm becoming nut.

I just wanted to make a simple and elegant animation when a screen is **focused** (in a tab bar navigation). My snack works perfectly **until I perform a state change** in my screen. Then the animation just won't start, even though the callback from focus listener is called and executed (check logs)... ***WHY?***

I made a button to trigger manually the animation... and it works!????
I think I made the snack clear, but if you need more information, please ask me. I beg you, please help a brother in despair.

**[Snack is here](https://snack.expo.io/4sln1SIMO)**

If you're lazy to click the Snack:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Text, View, Animated, Dimensions, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, Button } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

function HomeScreen({navigation}) {
  const initialXPos = Dimensions.get("window").height * 0.5 ;
  const xPos = new Animated.Value(initialXPos);
  const opacity = new Animated.Value(0);
  const [change, setChange] = useState(true)

   useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener("focus", comingFromBot);
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  const comingFromBot = () => {
    xPos.setValue(initialXPos);
    opacity.setValue(0);
    Animated.parallel([
      Animated.spring(xPos, {
        toValue: 100,
        tension:3,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }),
      Animated.timing(opacity, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 1000,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }),
    ]).start();
    console.log("Animation's Fired!");
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
      <Animated.View style={[
            styles.container,
            { transform: [{ translateY: xPos }] },
            { opacity: opacity },
          ]}>
        <Text style={{fontSize:30}}>{change ? "Home!" : "TIMMY!"}</Text>
      </Animated.View>

      {/* debug */}
      <View style={styles.fire}>
        <Button title="fire" onPress={() => comingFromBot()}/>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.change}>
        <Button title="change" onPress={() => setChange(!change)}/>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1, alignItems: 'center' },
  fire:{position:"absolute", width:"100%", bottom:0},
  change:{position:"absolute", width:"100%", bottom:48}
  });

function SettingsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', padding:8 }}>
      <Text>{"Go to Home tab again, and notice the animation.\n\nEXCEPT if we changed the text... WHY?\n\nBUT still works if we fire the animation with the button, but after still won't work on focus detection... HOW?\n\nWorks if you hot reload / hard reload the app... HELP?"}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyTabs />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended with this, thanks to @satya164: [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/2OV0yoipX)

I also wish I read this in [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/animations) before.

HomeScreen's code:

```js
// HomeScreen.js
function HomeScreen({navigation}) {
  const initialXPos = Dimensions.get("window").height * 0.5 ;
  const xPos = useRef(new Animated.Value(initialXPos)).current 
  const opacity = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current 
  const [change, setChange] = useState(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener("focus", comingFromBot);
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation, comingFromBot]);

  const comingFromBot = useCallback(() => {
    xPos.setValue(initialXPos);
    opacity.setValue(0);
    Animated.parallel([
      Animated.spring(xPos, {
        toValue: 100,
        tension:3,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }),
      Animated.timing(opacity, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 1000,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }),
    ]).start();
    console.log("Animation's Fired!");
  }, [xPos, opacity, initialXPos ]);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
      <Animated.View style={[
            styles.container,
            { transform: [{ translateY: xPos }] },
            { opacity: opacity },
          ]}>
        <Text style={{fontSize:30}}>{change ? "Home!" : "TIMMY!"}</Text>
      </Animated.View>

      {/* debug */}
      <View style={styles.fire}>
        <Button title="fire" onPress={() => comingFromBot()}/>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.change}>
        <Button title="change" onPress={() => setChange(!change)}/>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because you're not following the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). The following things are wrong in your code:

1. You're using variables from outside in `useEffect` hook, but passing empty dependency array
2. The animated values need to be in a `useState` or `useRef` hook so that they aren't recreated every render

> Then the animation just won't start, even though the callback from focus listener is called and executed (check logs)... WHY?

The problem is that the callback is recreated after state update on re-render, so the callback passed to the focus listener isn't the same as what's in render anymore. And since you also don't have your animated values in state/ref, new animated values are also created while the old focus listener is referring to the old values. Basically the log you see is from an old listener and not the new one.

You should use the [official eslint plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) and ensure that you fix all the warnings/errors from it so that such problems are avoided.

To fix your code, do the following changes:

```js
const [xPos] = React.useState(() => new Animated.Value(initialXPos));
const [opacity] = React.useState(() => new Animated.Value(0));
const [change, setChange] = useState(true)

useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener("focus", comingFromBot);
  return unsubscribe;
}, [navigation, comingFromBot]);

const comingFromBot = useCallback(() => {
  xPos.setValue(initialXPos);
  opacity.setValue(0);
  Animated.parallel([
    Animated.spring(xPos, {
      toValue: 100,
      tension:3,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }),
    Animated.timing(opacity, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 1000,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }),
  ]).start();
  console.log("Animation's Fired!");
}, [xPos, opacity]);
```

I basically added `useCallback`, fix the dependency arrays, and moved the animated values to `useState` hook.

Comment: Awesome, thank you @satya164. You made me understand many things. So I kept searching and I found out this works with ```useRef``` also: 

`const xPos = useRef(new Animated.Value(initialXPos)).current;`
`const opacity = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;`

By the way, is there a reason you wrote `useState(() => ...)`and not `useState(...)`?

Comment: Yes you can also use useRef. I used `useState(() => ...)` because that'll call `new Animated.Value()` only for the first render lazily and not every render. It probably doesn't make a lot of difference though.